# why doesn't my interpolated html display properly in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

The data in my app.js file is not being interpolated and displayed on the screen. I tried the older v-repeat. Could it be some missing items in the installation? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my html

```
<!-- show the events -->
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item" v-for="event in events">
        <!-- <h1>{{text}}</h1> -->
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></i> 
          {{ event.name }}
        </h4>

        <h5>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" v-if="event.date"></i> 
          {{ event.date }}
        </h5>

        <p class="list-group-item-text" v-if="event.description">{{ event.description }}</p>

        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" v-on="click: deleteEvent($index)">Delete</button>
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is my js file

```
new Vue({

data: {
    text: 'hello world',
  event: { name: '', description: '', date: '' },
  events: []
},

// Anything within the ready function will run when the application loads
ready: function() {
  // When the application loads, we want to call the method that initializes
  // some data
  this.fetchEvents();
},

// Methods we want to use in our application are registered here
methods: {

  // We dedicate a method to retrieving and setting some data
  fetchEvents: function() {
    var events = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'TIFF',
        description: 'Toronto International Film Festival',
        date: '2015-09-10'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'The Martian Premiere',
        description: 'The Martian comes to theatres.',
        date: '2015-10-02'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'SXSW',
        description: 'Music, film and interactive festival in Austin, TX.',
        date: '2016-03-11'
      }
    ];
    // $set is a convenience method provided by Vue that is similar to pushing
    // data onto an array
    this.$set('events', events);
  },

  // Adds an event to the existing events array
  addEvent: function() {
    if(this.event.name) {
      this.events.push(this.event);
      this.event = { name: '', description: '', date: '' };
    }
  }
}
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You're trying to use v1?

Comment: I'm using vue@2.3.3 and vue-resource@1.3.3. is that what you're asking?

Comment: I suggest you take a spin through the v2 docs. There is no `ready` in v2. You probably wanted `created` or `mounted`.

Comment: Also `this.$set('events', events)` should just be `this.events = events`.

Comment: oh good to know about these fundamental differences. ill take a look through and play with the code a bit. thanks

Answer (score 1):

So, there are a few issues here. I've cleaned them up for you to look over.

1. Added the `el: "#app"` property to tell Vue where to mount your Vue.
2. Changed your `ready` to `mounted` (you could also use `created`).
3. Changed `this.$set('events',events)` to `this.events = events`.
4. Added the unreferenced deleteEvent method.
5. Fixed the click handler syntax for `v-on:click`.

So the code ends up looking like this.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    text: 'hello world',
    event: { name: '', description: '', date: '' },
    events: []
  },
  mounted: function() {
      this.fetchEvents();
  },
  // Methods we want to use in our application are registered here
  methods: {

    // We dedicate a method to retrieving and setting some data
    fetchEvents: function() {
      var events = [...];
      this.events = events;
    },

    // Adds an event to the existing events array
    addEvent: function() {
      if(this.event.name) {
        this.events.push(this.event);
        this.event = { name: '', description: '', date: '' };
      }
    },
    deleteEvent(){
      alert('delete this one')
    }
  }
});
```

Template

```
<div id="app">
  <!-- show the events -->
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item" v-for="event in events">
        <!-- <h1>{{text}}</h1> -->
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></i> 
          {{ event.name }}
        </h4>

        <h5>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" v-if="event.date"></i> 
          {{ event.date }}
        </h5>

        <p class="list-group-item-text" v-if="event.description">{{ event.description }}</p>

        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" v-on:click=" deleteEvent(event)">Delete</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/zzxmYL?editors=1010).

Comment: Thank you Bert. That worked. A follow up question I have is ... so i have a form above the code you posted, and originally I wrapped everything - the form, and the html above - in a div container with the id="app". when i move the id back to the container div, nothing shows up on the screen. no errors, but the page doesn't render the content. When i move the id="app" back to where you had it, it displays. Any thoughts on why the location of el causes content to render or not render?

Comment: @JackDagley I would need to see the layout to be able to answer. If you want to throw it in the pen or a fiddle I'll take a look.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Here is the pen, in which i added the id="app" to the container div instead of the events list - https://codepen.io/jdagley77/pen/vZOmBw

Comment: @JackDagley Sorry for the delayed response. The reason nothing displays when you move the `id="app"` to the container is because of a syntax error on your `Submit` button, `<button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:"click: addEvent">Submit</button>`. That line should be this: `<button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="addEvent">Submit</button>`. Then everything will work fine.